# Windows 10 Printing RTF Document on CMD

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, rtf

It is known that the windows command prompt is capable of printing colored and formatted text.
So if I have an rtf void of images or other content, such that it is possible the windows command prompt can display the content, is there a way to do so.

I tried doing this using the `type` command in the command prompt.

[image: The RTF Document (named sample.rtf)]

When I put the command `type sample.rtf` this is the print received

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff3\adeflang1025
{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset2 Symbol;}{\f2\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f3\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Liberation Serif{\*\falt Times New Roman};}{\f4\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Liberation Sans{\*\falt Arial};}{\f5\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 Microsoft YaHei;}{\f6\fnil\fprq0\fcharset128 Mangal;}{\f7\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 Mangal;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue128;\red0\green128\blue0;\red128\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;\red192\green192\blue192;\red212\green234\blue107;}
{\stylesheet{\s0\snext0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1 Normal;}
{\s15\sbasedon0\snext16\dbch\af5\dbch\af7\afs28\sb240\sa120\keepn\loch\f4\fs28 Heading;}
{\s16\sbasedon0\snext16\sl276\slmult1\sb0\sa140 Text Body;}
{\s17\sbasedon16\snext17\dbch\af6\sl276\slmult1\sb0\sa140 List;}
{\s18\sbasedon0\snext18\dbch\af6\afs24\ai\sb120\sa120\noline\fs24\i Caption;}
{\s19\sbasedon0\snext19\dbch\af6\noline Index;}
}{\*\generator LibreOffice/6.4.5.2$Windows_X86_64 LibreOffice_project/a726b36747cf2001e06b58ad5db1aa3a9a1872d6}{\info{\creatim\yr0\mo0\dy0\hr0\min0}{\revtim\yr2020\mo9\dy15\hr20\min40}{\printim\yr0\mo0\dy0\hr0\min0}}{\*\userprops}\deftab709\hyphauto1\viewscale75
{\*\pgdsctbl
{\pgdsc0\pgdscuse451\pgwsxn11906\pghsxn16838\marglsxn1134\margrsxn1134\margtsxn1134\margbsxn1134\pgdscnxt0 Default Style;}}
\formshade\paperh16838\paperw11906\margl1134\margr1134\margt1134\margb1134\sectd\sbknone\sectunlocked1\pgndec\pgwsxn11906\pghsxn16838\marglsxn1134\margrsxn1134\margtsxn1134\margbsxn1134\ftnbj\ftnstart1\ftnrstcont\ftnnar\aenddoc\aftnrstcont\aftnstart1\aftnnrlc
{\*\ftnsep\chftnsep}\pgndec\pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar\loch

\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar{\loch
This is just a sample text}
\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar\loch

\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar{\rtlch\ab \ltrch\b\loch
This is just a sample bold text  }
\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar\rtlch\ab \ltrch\b\loch

\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar{\rtlch\ai\ab0 \ltrch\i\b0\loch
This is just a sample  italics text }
\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar\rtlch\ai\ab0 \ltrch\i\b0\loch

\par \pard\plain \s0\hich\af3\dbch\af8\langfe2052\dbch\af7\afs24\alang1081\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\ltrpar\cf0\loch\f3\fs24\lang16393\kerning1\ql\ltrpar{\rtlch\ai\ab0 \ltrch\cf17\i\b0\loch
This is just a sample coloured text }
\par }
```

I understand that this is the ANSI/Unicode equivalent data and metadata of the RTF which when processed in a word processor yields the formatted text. Is there a way to print the RTF as it is on the command prompt. Also if such a command exists, how does it deal with images and other content which might not be under the capacity of the command prompt to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't view/print rich formatted documents on Command Prompt. Text editors and terminal emulators can't render rich formatted documents. You need word processor like Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer, Wordpad etc.

Comment: Is there any CLI interface application(Third-party) that lets me do the printing on the command prompt?

Comment: No, I don't see any tools available for this.

Comment: 'It is known that the windows command prompt is capable of printing colored and formatted text'.. to the console? sure! .. to a print driver?.. no.  Ansi color sequences are not RTF and print drivers don't even interpret RTF.. it takes YET ANOTHER program to convert RTF to "device context" GDI commands.

Comment: Yes, you are right @SeñorCMasMas, that cmd.exe can show ANSI colored text and fonts can be changed, but can't interpret GDI calls. ANSI formatting is not rich formatted text.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas so would there be a certain format (Graphically or otherwise) that if encoded properly in; can print formatted text to the console? I tried ANSI escape sequences but they don't seem to work on txt or other file types.

Comment: To be honest Aniruddh, I am not sure.  When I need that, I usually screen shot the console and don't try to get text.. sorry I can't be much help here.